# Create postgres schema and tables dynamically in springboot application

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, saas

I am building a SaaS application using postgres and Springboot, and I am using both for the first time. I want a new schema to be created when a new user registers to our application. I tried using stored procedures, but I am able to create a procedure on a schema only. So no new schema will be created. I googled for answers and found options to create schema and tables during initialisation. Is there a way to do it dynamically during run time? Thanks!

Comment: What do you use to access the data? JPA? Raw Hibernate? Jooq? Plain JDBC / JDBC Template? Spring Data?

Comment: We are using JPA.